# Creating dynamic arrays without "new" in VC++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create an array in Visual Studio as it is possible in C99:

```
int function(int N)
{
    int x[N];
    return 1;
};
```

But even VS2013 doesn't support this. Is there another way (except using new and delete) to create `x` without the need to fix N at translation time?
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, the value of N must be known at compile-time.

Comment: Wait for the C++14 TS. It's not standard C++.

Comment: @DerFlatulator: So I have to use new because VS20xx doesn't support C99 completely?

Comment: @arc_lupus Since C++ is not C, support of C99 has nothing to do with inability to declare variable-size arrays in C++.

Comment: It is not VS 20xx that doesn't support C99. It is the C++ Standard that doesn't support C99.

Comment: @arc_lupus Replace `int x[N];` with `std::vector<int> x(N)`.

Comment: @arc_lupus: Which do you want to write? C or C++? The fact that the code is ill-formed C++ is not affected in any way by inclusion (or exclusion) of a C99 or C11 implementation in the same package.

Comment: you don't _have_ to use `new`, you could use `malloc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condoned way of doing this in C++ is by using vectors

```
#include <vector>

int function(int N)
{
    std::vector<int> x(N);
    return 1;
};
```

If you know that N won't be enormous (and since you seem to want this memory on the stack, anyway), you can use `_alloca`, which is a C function. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx).

```
#include <malloc.h>

int function(int N)
{
    int *x = _alloca(sizeof(int)*N);
    return 1;
};
```

This isn't really recommended, and has been superceded by [`_malloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx), which requires a call to `_freea` after you're done with the memory.

Note that both versions will free the memory when the function exits, but the first version will allocate memory on the heap, whereas the second will allocate on the stack (and therefore has a much stricter upper limit on `N`). Besides the convenience and low-overhead of the `std::vector` class, using C-style pointers in a C++ program is kind of a downer anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order for an array in C++ to be defined on the stack (i.e. without `new`), the size of it must be known at compile time, such as a `const int` or a preprocessor macro. As this is not the case in this situation, you can use the following instead:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// ...
int function(int n)
{
    vector<int> x (n);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a possibily to define a variable length array in the stack in C++. But you can use std::vector instead though it allocates memory in the heap.